# Jquary UI resizable scaling not working properly with CSS flex box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, flexbox

I have created this scalable divs UI using the Jquery UI library and CSS flexbox. Here I can add multiple scalable divs using this "Add panel" button click. Newly add panels will adjust according to wrapper div size. But when I scale the individual div it's not scaling correctly and it's getting dragged. Is there a way I can use jquery UI with CSS flexbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  var $element =  '<div class="inner-pannel"> </div>'; 
  
  $( ".add-btn" ).click(function() {
      $('.wrapper').append($element);
    
        $(".inner-pannel").resizable({
                handles: 'w,e',
                minWidth: 250,
                maxWidth: 1000,
                resizeHeight: false,
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                },
    });
  });
  
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 7px;
    height: 50vh;
  
}

.inner-pannel{
    flex: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button class="add-btn"> Add panel </button> 

<div class="wrapper">  

</div>
```

Comment: "when I scale the individual div" please also  add example of this case.

Comment: do you need horizontal scroll or every second div should show next line?